# How much money do you need to start rebuilding the village?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I've recently finished the "Nest of vipers" main quest and decided to start "[From the ashes](https://kingdom-come-deliverance.fandom.com/wiki/From_the_Ashes)" DLC quest, where I was named as a bailiff of a new Pribyslavitz village and ordered to rebuild it. I was feeling very rich having on me about 4.5 k of groschen... until I've found the costs of labour and buildings on the wiki site: a simple woodcutter site costs 2.5k, trader - 4k, church - 35k. And all this doesn't include daily wages.

Yes, some of those buildings produce income, but in general, it is a GIGANTIC money sink.

So reasonably speaking, how much money do I need to start thinking about restoring the village?

Answer (score 5):

To make the village self-sufficient (I mean, providing minimal profit) you need to first build the basics

To do that you need to first:

- Build woodcutters for 2500
- Build a road and bridge for 4000
- Build a trader for 4000
- Get supply of grain - cheapest from Samopesh for 80

So this costs 11500 payable once and ~325 per day in costs.

Now you have a choice:

1. Build a bakery and drying shed upgrade for 4700  - this will net you 85 groschen profit per day
2. Get a supply of stone for 3000 (taken down from 4k if you pass the speech) and build a tavern for 8000 giving you 175 groschens per day

So not counting daily expenses, this will cost you 15280 or 21580 groschens. Now, if you can afford, go with the second option, since tavern can be upgraded for extra 3000 to provide an additional 500 groschens a day

Comment: Please note that the cost for grain, meat, and coal (but NOT stone) is DAILY. All other costs are one-time only.

Comment: Also, you can recruit several NPC who generally improve your income to work in your buildings : for instance, you may convince Kunesh (in Rattay) and Raspberry (south of the Inn in the Glade) to work as woodcutters (once you have the camp).
For the merchant, Kornelius (in Rattay) might want to work for you, depending on if and how you ended the Aquarius quest.

As for the tavern, you can hire Mirka (at the Merhojed mill), and Adam (at one of Rattay's taverns) or maybe Alex (at the Inn in the Glade). You may have to be sufficently advanced in the main or secondary quests though.

Answer (score 1):

I started with 100k in the chest. After all the buildings and upgrades, I had 43k left. So 57k is roughly what you need.